# how to substitute minus sign with tr

Tags: tr

I'm trying to replace several symbols with spaces, and I thought `tr` was the right command. So I tried

```
cat myfile | tr '_[]()-/' ' '
```

But I get the error

```
range-endpoints of ']-/' are in reverse collating sequence order
```

presumably because I can't have a minus sign in the input characters. Can I accomplish this using `tr`?

Comment: what version of `tr` are you using?  what OS?   GNU `tr` copes with this without a problem.  Other versions of `tr` may require some of the characters to be escaped.

Comment: `tr -- '-_[]()/' ' '`

Answer (score 4):

The message apparently comes from GNU `tr`, and perhaps is due to some issue with locale settings.  The *info* page for `tr` suggests putting the `-` last in the set, to avoid confusing it as part of a *range*, e.g.,

```
cat myfile | tr '_[]()/-' ' '
```

Comment: Work fine with `tr (GNU coreutils) 8.23`

Comment: Google found several comments all related to GNU coreutils, but I found no relevant bug reports - a better answer would replicate OP's problem.  I tested with 8.23 and 8.13 (no warnings).

Comment: Thank you - simply putting the minus last in the set solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX `tr`:

```
tr '_][()/-' '[ *]' <file
```

will work.

Note that the use of `[ *]` is required by POSIX. In:

```
tr string1 string2
```

When *string2* shorter than *string1*, a BSD `tr` will pad *string2* with the last character of *string2*, so `tr '_][()/-' ' '` is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I considered that also, but setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` failed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you - simply putting the minus last in the set solved the problem